# type of explicit numbers in Xcode

Tags: c++

```
#include <complex>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    complex<float> a(1,1);
    cout<<1.0+a<<endl;
}
```

Here is a short c++ code I wrote in Xcode, and when compile, it displays an error message

```
Invalid operands to binary operation('double' and 'complex<float>')
```

which means, the compiler has taken 1.0 as double type. But what I want is a float type number, what can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: The standard term (useful for e.g. googling) is "literal", not "explicit".

Answer (score 0):

By default floating point literal values like <kbd>1.0</kbd> and <kbd>200.0</kbd> are type `double`. You can force them to type `float` by appending an `f` to the literal value in your code like so

```
std::cout << 1.0f + a << std::endl;
               _^_
```